# Rails with mysql can't save json datatype

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, json

I have create Rails(3.2) application with mysql(5.7.16) backend. I can't save json data and I have pass value like following and it shows error like

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - Mysql2::Error: Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 1 in value for column 'shopping_cart_item_special_infos.special_info'.: INSERT INTO `shopping_cart_item_special_infos` (`created_at`, `shopping_cart_checkout_option_id`, `special_info`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2016-12-29 06:08:52', 141, '--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess\n\'201\': text1\n\'209\': \'623\'\n\'210\': \'625\'\n\'211\': text2\n', '2016-12-29 06:08:52'):
>     activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:285:in `rescue in log'
>     activerecord (3.2.21) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in`log'
>     newrelic_rpm (3.9.1.236) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_record.rb:63:in `block in log_with_newrelic_i

```
{"201"=>"text1", "209"=>"623", "210"=>"625", "211"=>"text2"}
```

What was wrong here ?

Comment: add error message in text not image

Comment: Deepak: I have edited question

Comment: is this your exact json ? which you are going to store?

Comment: @Amruth: Yes. I am going to store above json.

Comment: @anandh check your json http://jsonlint.com/ here i think its invalid

Comment: {"201"=>"text1", "209"=>'623', "210"=>'625', "211"=>"text2"} use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I fixed above error by to_json method

Ex)

```
{"201"=>"text1", "209"=>"623", "210"=>"625", "211"=>"text2"}.to_json
```

**NOTE**: I am used to_json because I am not serialised value as JSON using code like

```
serialize :special_info, JSON
```

If I used above code then no need to convert using as_json, it will automatically parse above data as json data otherwise it consider the data as string.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON should be like this

```
{"201":"text1", "209":"623", "210":"625", "211":"text2"}
```

But you are passing a ruby hash

Check the difference between `=>` and `:`

And as @amruth-ls suggested you can validate your JSON at [**`jsonlint`**](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: @anandh That is probably because you are trying to evaluate JSON in the ruby compiler... which does not work. JSON syntax is not recognised by ruby unlike the Hash object. JSON syntax can be parsed from a string into a Hash or vice verse but usually when you want to store a data structure from Ruby into a database, then you would use a column that serialises the Hash object instead of JSON. But as long as you found a way to solve it...